# Give every 4th Element with same class another class

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I  am building a Menu with 9 blocks in 3 rows with 3 blocks in each row, in JS and XML like this:

JS:

```
menu += '<div class="col col-12 col-lg-4"><div class="lorem">'

menu += '</div></div>'
```

XML:

```
<item id="1" .....><![CDATA[x]]></item>
<item id="2" .....><![CDATA[x]]></item>
<item id="3" .....><![CDATA[x]]></item>
```

etc.

I want to make a section scroll, because I margined every row with a big gap so they are seperated with a huge space, and the user should have it easier with a hard scroll.

I could do that with different classes for every section or with `<section>` seperation, but I can't figure out a way to give every other row the class or the tag.
Now I can build a querySelector to select every Element with the same class, but this won't seperate them in every section.

Comment: what is it actually you want to achieve as final result. Giving every 4th element a different class might be a hard workaroudn to a simple issue that properly could be solved with  `nth-child(4n)`

Comment: nth-child(4n) ?

Comment: `:nth-child()`  is a pseudo-selector for CSS. `4n` means every 4th child in this case

Comment: yea, but with that option I could only change the CSS. How can I turn that into a section scroll ?

Comment: what do you mean with section scroll

Comment: https://codepen.io/alexzhav/pen/Yzzxgqd

Comment: I see, but that wont work with adding a class to every 4th element. You have to wrap the first 3 elements into a section with JS. YOu can also sue the nth-child pseudo-selector within JS querySelector

Comment: How could that work ? I mean how can I implement nth-child to my example ? I only see nth-child with example where the code contains <section>